# Ctrl is stuck frequently

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use Code Runner for running Stata.
I use Ctrl+D as a shortcut for Code Runner.
The issue is that ctrl is stuck too frequently. It means that Ctrl is pushed permanently on keyboard even if I do not push Ctrl.

Is this bug a rare event that only I am experencing? or is it a common bug and there is a solution?

Comment: I've used VSCode for many years and never had that issue. Do you experience the same thing if you don't have Code Runner installed? Also are you updated to the newest version of VSCode?

Comment: Do you have sticky keys on?

Comment: Is your keyboard broken?

Comment: @AlecMather @ Roddy of the Frozen Peas:
 I have not tested without Code Runner since it is my most important extension. I tested on several different pc, and many other keyboards, but the same issue happens....

Comment: @Andoo I don't know what is skicky keys. Therefore, I guess I dont have it on.

Comment: Sticky keys is an accessibility feature that allows modifier keys like Ctrl and Shift to remain active even when you're not pressing them. Depending on your computer, OS, and settings, they may be automatically enabled. Also, in Windows, you can accidentally it on by pressing Shift five times. Next time you notice your issue, check to make sure that sticky keys isn't on (either look for the icon in the overflow tray or try keyboard shortcuts in another app). If it is, that's an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

Does the issue occur when using other programs, or only in VSCode? What operating system is your machine running? Have you checked keyboard shortcuts? If it is a Windows system, you can try the following:

```
ctrl + alt + delete and then esc out of that window. It should reset the key status.

Press both left and right ctrl buttons (also should reset key status)
```

Comment: It occurs whenever I use only in VSCODE. It does not occur in other programs. I formatted the entire C driver several times because if this issue, but the issue persists whenever I use VS Code. 

When CTRL is stuck, I do the same trick as you mentioned. It resets the key status and the stuck issue solves.